# Что значит log group capacity?

Tags: mysql, логирование

В логе ошибок mysql найдены следующие строки:

```
180220  2:14:33  InnoDB: ERROR: the age of the last checkpoint is 990314889,
InnoDB: which exceeds the log group capacity 966363956.
InnoDB: If you are using big BLOB or TEXT rows, you must set the
InnoDB: combined size of log files at least 10 times bigger than the
InnoDB: largest such row.
```

Но в то же время запрос:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_log_file_size';
```

возвращает значение `536870912 (512 MB)`. Что тогда значит `log group capacity` и откуда берётся его значение - `966363956`?

**UPD**

Согласно [ответу на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18811422/4898850), `log group capacity` должен быть равным

`innodb_log_file_size * innodb_log_files_in_group`

Но почему-то это условие не выполняется ни у меня, ни для соответствующего ответу лога (в [вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18806377/4898850)):

536870912 * 2 = 1073741824 (1073741824 != 966363956).